# multiply two fields (one fo them is a label, the other is text box) and display in a label javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have found one answer to a previous question i posted on here a couple of days ago and now i run into another issue.  I am trying to Multiple a Label with a fix Value that can change depending on a click.  This is for a dollar amount to be multiplied by another number in a text field and then display in a label.

Here is a segment from the form that you can see the three areas i am dealing with:

```
<td class="cbFormLabelCell cbFormLabel">Ticket Price</td>
<td  class="cbFormNestedTableContainer">
<table  class="cbFormNestedTableCellspacing cbFormNestedTable">
<tr>
<td class="cbFormDataCellNumberDate"><span class="cbFormData">$100.00</span>
<input type="hidden" name="InsertRecordTicket_Price" value="100.00"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cbFormTableEvenRow">
<td class="cbFormLabelCell cbFormLabelRequired"><label for="InsertRecordNumber_of_Tickets" >Number of Tickets<span class="cbFormRequiredMarker">*</span></label></td>
<td class="cbFormFieldCell"><input type="text" maxlength="3" name="InsertRecordNumber_of_Tickets" id="InsertRecordNumber_of_Tickets" value=""  class="cbFormTextField"  size="3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="cbFormTableRow">
<td class="cbFormLabelCell cbFormLabel">Total Amount</td>
<td class="cbFormDataCell">
<span class="cbFormData">&nbsp;</span>
<input type="hidden" name="cbParamVirtual4" value=""/></td>
```

Here is the Java script code i am trying to get to work with the form from above:

```
var Ticket_PriceField = document.getElementById('InsertRecordTicket_Price');
var Number_of_TicketsField = document.getElementsById('InsertRecordNumber_of_Tickets');
//I would like to know which way to go with the total field?  I have put both otpions down below.
var totalField = document.querySelectorAll('span[class^="cbParamVirtual4"]')[0];

var totalField = document.getElementById('cbParamVirtual4');

var calculateTotal = function (event)
{
// TODO: Do something on value change -->
totalField.innerHTML = Ticket_PriceField.value * Number_of_TicketsField.value;
}
// Run total calculation on input 
Number_of_TicketsField.addEventListener('input', calculateTotal);
```

Also just to inform you i am not working on this in a code envronment.  The is a custom system that i can do some manipulation with but dont know how much more i can do with the system.  So i cant just edit the form and make it work.  I have tested the code that way and it works perfect.  I think i am just missing something small right now.  I can go in and do custom javascript in the system but that is about it.  No html coding.

If any of you could give me some help on this i would appreciate it a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the totalField use getElementsByName. See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp.

Example:

```
var totalField = document.getElementsByName('cbParamVirtual4')[0];
```

Set the value of the total field using the value property:

```
if (totalField != null) {
    totalField.value = Ticket_PriceField.value * Number_of_TicketsField.value;
}
```

The rest of your code looks fine.

Comment: Here is the updated javascript.  I have tried the update that you showed and when i move away from the tickets nothing happened.

'var totalField = document.querySelectorAll('span[class^="cbFormData"]')[0];
var totalField = document.getElementsByName('cbParamVirtual4')[0];
Number_of_TicketsField.addEventListener('input', calculateTotal);
// Event handler
var calculateTotal = function (event)
{
// TODO: Do something on value change -->
if (totalField != null) {
    totalField.value = Ticket_PriceField.value * Number_of_TicketsField.value;
}
}'

Comment: Looking at your code, InsertRecordTicket_Price does not have an ID attache. Use document.getElementsByName (as explained) to get the element.

Comment: I have updated the code but still not showing up in total value area.  

var Ticket_PriceField = document.getElementByName('InsertRecordTicket_Price');
var Number_of_TicketsField = document.getElementById('InsertRecordNumber_of_Tickets');
var totalField = document.querySelectorAll('span[class^="cbFormData"]')[0];
var totalFieldVal = document.getElementsByName('cbParamVirtual4')[0];

Comment: Here is the updated function:

var calculateTotal = function (event)
{
// TODO: Do something on value change -->
totalField.innerHTML = Ticket_PriceField.value * Number_of_TicketsField.value;
 if (totalFieldVal != null) { totalFieldVal.value = Ticket_PriceField.value * Number_of_TicketsField.value; }
}
Number_of_TicketsField.addEventListener('input', calculateTotal);

Comment: For the ticket price field, you're using document.getElementByName which doesn't exist. Use document.getElementsByName(''InsertRecordTicket_Price')[0]

Comment: Thank you for your help there.  I just have one issue now.  the price is showing up but not in the right place.  here is a link to the image of what i am talking about.  The 200 is showing up at the top of the page not in the total price area.  [link](http://demositepca.com/price-onpage.html)  Again Thank you for your help.  Could you let me know what you think the issue is.

Comment: here is the script that is working:


<script>
var Ticket_PriceField = document.getElementsByName('InsertRecordTicket_Price')[0];
var Number_of_TicketsField = document.getElementById('InsertRecordNumber_of_Tickets');
var totalField = document.querySelectorAll('span[class^="cbFormData"]')[0];
// Run total calculation on input
var calculateTotal = function (event)
{
// TODO: Do something on value change -->
totalField.innerHTML = Ticket_PriceField.value * Number_of_TicketsField.value;
}
Number_of_TicketsField.addEventListener('input', calculateTotal);
</script>

Comment: I need to display the data in the <input type="hidden" name="cbParamVirtual4" value=""/>.